# Using Java libraries with ColdFusion 9

Tags: java, coldfusion, iis-7.5, coldfusion-9

I am currently running a Java application which applies some natural language processing techniques to analyze data. This application includes a Java Class file and 1 library of .bin extension
The application works fine on my development server but on the live server I get the error below:

Object instantiation exception.
An exception occurred while instantiating a Java object. The class must not be an interface or an abstract class. `Error: opennlp/tools/util/ObjectStream.`

> Stack Trace java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   opennlp/tools/util/ObjectStream
>           at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
>           at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2291)
>           at java.lang.Class.privateGetPublicFields(Class.java:2324)
>           at java.lang.Class.getFields(Class.java:1359)
>           at coldfusion.runtime.java.ObjectHandler.Initialize(ObjectHandler.java:35)
>           at coldfusion.runtime.java.ObjectHandler.(ObjectHandler.java:30)
>           at coldfusion.runtime.java.ReflectionCache$1.fetch(ReflectionCache.java:29)
>           at coldfusion.util.SoftCache.get_statsOff(SoftCache.java:133)
>           at coldfusion.util.SoftCache.get(SoftCache.java:81)
>           at coldfusion.runtime.java.ReflectionCache.get(ReflectionCache.java:36)
>           at coldfusion.runtime.java.JavaProxy.(JavaProxy.java:35)
>           at coldfusion.runtime.java.JavaProxyFactory.getProxy(JavaProxyFactory.java:89)
>           at coldfusion.runtime.ProxyFactory.getProxy(ProxyFactory.java:65)
>           at coldfusion.runtime.CFPage.createObjectProxy(CFPage.java:5002)
>           at coldfusion.runtime.CFPage.CreateObject(CFPage.java:4966)
>           at coldfusion.runtime.CFPage.CreateObject(CFPage.java:4907)
>           at coldfusion.runtime.CFPage.CreateObject(CFPage.java:4885)
>           at coldfusion.runtime.CFPage.CreateObject(CFPage.java:4842)
>           at cfWord_Cloud_Report2ecfm2061667591.runPage(E:\sites\SignatureWebMedical.Com\cf_modules\reports\sounding\Word_Cloud_Report.cfm:40)
>           at coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage.invoke(CfJspPage.java:231)
>           at coldfusion.tagext.lang.IncludeTag.doStartTag(IncludeTag.java:416)
>           at coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage._emptyTcfTag(CfJspPage.java:2722)
>           at cfindex2ecfm1980726432._factor0(E:\sites_virtualdirs\admin\reports\index.cfm:425)
>           at cfindex2ecfm1980726432._factor7(E:\sites_virtualdirs\admin\reports\index.cfm:403)
>           at cfindex2ecfm1980726432._factor8(E:\sites_virtualdirs\admin\reports\index.cfm:188)
>           at cfindex2ecfm1980726432.runPage(E:\sites_virtualdirs\admin\reports\index.cfm:1)
>           at coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage.invoke(CfJspPage.java:231)
>           at coldfusion.tagext.lang.IncludeTag.doStartTag(IncludeTag.java:416)
>           at coldfusion.filter.CfincludeFilter.invoke(CfincludeFilter.java:65)
>           at coldfusion.filter.ApplicationFilter.invoke(ApplicationFilter.java:360)
>           at coldfusion.filter.RequestMonitorFilter.invoke(RequestMonitorFilter.java:48)
>           at coldfusion.filter.MonitoringFilter.invoke(MonitoringFilter.java:40)
>           at coldfusion.filter.PathFilter.invoke(PathFilter.java:94)
>           at coldfusion.filter.ExceptionFilter.invoke(ExceptionFilter.java:70)
>           at coldfusion.filter.ClientScopePersistenceFilter.invoke(ClientScopePersistenceFilter.java:28)
>           at coldfusion.filter.BrowserFilter.invoke(BrowserFilter.java:38)
>           at coldfusion.filter.NoCacheFilter.invoke(NoCacheFilter.java:46)
>           at coldfusion.filter.GlobalsFilter.invoke(GlobalsFilter.java:38)
>           at coldfusion.filter.DatasourceFilter.invoke(DatasourceFilter.java:22)
>           at coldfusion.filter.CachingFilter.invoke(CachingFilter.java:62)
>           at coldfusion.filter.RequestThrottleFilter.invoke(RequestThrottleFilter.java:126)
>           at coldfusion.CfmServlet.service(CfmServlet.java:200)
>           at coldfusion.bootstrap.BootstrapServlet.service(BootstrapServlet.java:89)
>           at jrun.servlet.FilterChain.doFilter(FilterChain.java:86)
>           at com.intergral.fusionreactor.filter.FusionReactorFilter.b(FusionReactorFilter.java:376)
>           at com.intergral.fusionreactor.filter.FusionReactorFilter.c(FusionReactorFilter.java:254)
>           at com.intergral.fusionreactor.filter.FusionReactorFilter.doFilter(FusionReactorFilter.java:164)
>           at jrun.servlet.FilterChain.doFilter(FilterChain.java:94)
>           at coldfusion.monitor.event.MonitoringServletFilter.doFilter(MonitoringServletFilter.java:42)
>           at coldfusion.bootstrap.BootstrapFilter.doFilter(BootstrapFilter.java:46)
>           at jrun.servlet.FilterChain.doFilter(FilterChain.java:94)
>           at jrun.servlet.FilterChain.service(FilterChain.java:101)
>           at jrun.servlet.ServletInvoker.invoke(ServletInvoker.java:106)
>           at jrun.servlet.JRunInvokerChain.invokeNext(JRunInvokerChain.java:42)
>           at jrun.servlet.JRunRequestDispatcher.invoke(JRunRequestDispatcher.java:286)
>           at jrun.servlet.ServletEngineService.dispatch(ServletEngineService.java:543)
>           at jrun.servlet.jrpp.JRunProxyService.invokeRunnable(JRunProxyService.java:203)
>           at jrunx.scheduler.ThreadPool$DownstreamMetrics.invokeRunnable(ThreadPool.java:320)
>           at jrunx.scheduler.ThreadPool$ThreadThrottle.invokeRunnable(ThreadPool.java:428)
>           at jrunx.scheduler.ThreadPool$UpstreamMetrics.invokeRunnable(ThreadPool.java:266)
>           at jrunx.scheduler.WorkerThread.run(WorkerThread.java:66)
>   **Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:opennlp.tools.util.ObjectStream**
>           at coldfusion.bootstrap.BootstrapClassLoader.loadClass(BootstrapClassLoader.java:235)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:316)
>           ... 61 more

It seems to me that it’s a class path issue. I had the same problem with the Dev server but fixed it by placing all my files in the Cold Fusion 9 directory: `C:\ColdFusion9\runtime\servers\lib`
When I place the class file and library .bin file in the same folder on the Live server it does not work.
I restart my production server every time I am adding/deleting the class file and .bin files.

Comment: Is your production server using a different JVM than the one in C:\ColdFusion9\runtime?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My issue was the versions of windows. On development we are using Windows server 2008 R2 and on production we were using Windows server 2008 SP2, which based on what I read online they have a lot differences (minor but important) We updated our production server on Friday and everything started working. Thanks to all that replied to this post.

Answer (score 2):

Did  you check if the class path is added in the ColdFusion Administrator Java JVM settings ?

Comment: yes. This is it right? `C:/ColdFusion9/runtime/jre` That is the default one. I did not make any changes to it.

Comment: Is this where I have to add my files or I'm doing something wrong? Please note that the same practice works on my development environment

Answer (score 0):

This might be similar to what you are dealing with: https://newrelic.com/docs/java/installing-the-java-agent-on-coldfusion