# How to call a java class in ColdFusion 11

Tags: coldfusion, opennlp, coldfusion-11

I am trying to use a java class file called Open_NLP but I am running into issues.

This is what I did so far

• Added the class file in `C:\ColdFusion11\cfusion\wwwroot\WEB-INF\classes` 
• Restarted the CF service

This is how I am calling it

```
<cfset myObj = CreateObject("java", "Open_NLP")>
```

And this is the Error I am getting

```
Object instantiation exception.

    An exception occurred while instantiating a Java object. The class must not be an interface or an abstract class. Error: opennlp/tools/util/ObjectStream.
```

Am I calling the class wrong? Do I have to take more steps before I am able to call the class?

```
Stack Trace
at cfwordcloud2ecfm316238315.runPage(Z:/Sites/xamplifier/views/surveyreporting/wordcloud.cfm:91) at cfcfml2ecfm1851198363$func$INCLUDEANDRETURNOUTPUT.runFunction(Z:/Sites/xamplifier/wheels/global/cfml.cfm:138) at cfrendering2ecfm1331024027$func$INCLUDEFILE.runFunction(Z:/Sites/xamplifier/wheels/controller/rendering.cfm:498) at cfrendering2ecfm1331024027$func$RENDERPAGE.runFunction(Z:/Sites/xamplifier/wheels/controller/rendering.cfm:257) at cfrendering2ecfm1331024027$funcRENDERPAGE.runFunction(Z:/Sites/xamplifier/wheels/controller/rendering.cfm:68) at cfprocessing2ecfm608176556$func$CALLACTION.runFunction(Z:/Sites/xamplifier/wheels/controller/processing.cfm:99) at cfprocessing2ecfm608176556$func$PROCESSACTION.runFunction(Z:/Sites/xamplifier/wheels/controller/processing.cfm:60) at cfrequest2ecfm2131921479$func$REQUEST.runFunction(Z:/Sites/xamplifier/wheels/dispatch/request.cfm:167) at cfindex2ecfm2029461072.runPage(Z:/Sites/xamplifier/wheels/index.cfm:1) at cfindex2ecfm1778521657.runPage(Z:/Sites/xamplifier/index.cfm:1) at cfonrequest2ecfm1108885784$funcONREQUEST.runFunction(Z:/Sites/xamplifier/wheels/events/onrequest.cfm:1) 
 at cfwordcloud2ecfm316238315.runPage(Z:/Sites/xamplifier/views/surveyreporting/wordcloud.cfm:91) at cfcfml2ecfm1851198363$func$INCLUDEANDRETURNOUTPUT.runFunction(Z:/Sites/xamplifier/wheels/global/cfml.cfm:138) at cfrendering2ecfm1331024027$func$INCLUDEFILE.runFunction(Z:/Sites/xamplifier/wheels/controller/rendering.cfm:498) at cfrendering2ecfm1331024027$func$RENDERPAGE.runFunction(Z:/Sites/xamplifier/wheels/controller/rendering.cfm:257) at cfrendering2ecfm1331024027$funcRENDERPAGE.runFunction(Z:/Sites/xamplifier/wheels/controller/rendering.cfm:68) at cfprocessing2ecfm608176556$func$CALLACTION.runFunction(Z:/Sites/xamplifier/wheels/controller/processing.cfm:99) at cfprocessing2ecfm608176556$func$PROCESSACTION.runFunction(Z:/Sites/xamplifier/wheels/controller/processing.cfm:60) at cfrequest2ecfm2131921479$func$REQUEST.runFunction(Z:/Sites/xamplifier/wheels/dispatch/request.cfm:167) at cfindex2ecfm2029461072.runPage(Z:/Sites/xamplifier/wheels/index.cfm:1) at cfindex2ecfm1778521657.runPage(Z:/Sites/xamplifier/index.cfm:1) at cfonrequest2ecfm1108885784$funcONREQUEST.runFunction(Z:/Sites/xamplifier/wheels/events/onrequest.cfm:1) 

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: opennlp/tools/util/ObjectStream
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetPublicFields(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getFields(Unknown Source)
    at coldfusion.runtime.java.ObjectHandler.Initialize(ObjectHandler.java:35)
    at coldfusion.runtime.java.ObjectHandler.<init>(ObjectHandler.java:30)
    at coldfusion.runtime.java.ReflectionCache.get(ReflectionCache.java:38)
    at coldfusion.runtime.java.JavaProxy.<init>(JavaProxy.java:35)
    at coldfusion.runtime.java.JavaProxyFactory.getProxy(JavaProxyFactory.java:121)
    at coldfusion.runtime.ProxyFactory.getProxy(ProxyFactory.java:65)
    at coldfusion.runtime.CFPage.createObjectProxy(CFPage.java:6168)
    at coldfusion.runtime.CFPage.CreateObject(CFPage.java:6131)
    at coldfusion.runtime.CFPage.CreateObject(CFPage.java:6065)
    at coldfusion.runtime.CFPage.CreateObject(CFPage.java:6040)
    at coldfusion.runtime.CFPage.CreateObject(CFPage.java:5987)
    at cfwordcloud2ecfm316238315.runPage(Z:\Sites\xamplifier\views\surveyreporting\wordcloud.cfm:91)
    at coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage.invoke(CfJspPage.java:246)
    at coldfusion.tagext.lang.IncludeTag.handlePageInvoke(IncludeTag.java:736)
    at coldfusion.tagext.lang.IncludeTag.doStartTag(IncludeTag.java:572)
    at coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage._emptyTcfTag(CfJspPage.java:2986)
    at cfcfml2ecfm1851198363$func$INCLUDEANDRETURNOUTPUT.runFunction(Z:\Sites\xamplifier\wheels\global\cfml.cfm:138)
    at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.invoke(UDFMethod.java:487)
    at coldfusion.filter.SilentFilter.invoke(SilentFilter.java:47)
    at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod$ReturnTypeFilter.invoke(UDFMethod.java:420)
    at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod$ArgumentCollectionFilter.invoke(UDFMethod.java:383)
    at coldfusion.filter.FunctionAccessFilter.invoke(FunctionAccessFilter.java:95)
    at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.runFilterChain(UDFMethod.java:334)
    at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.invoke(UDFMethod.java:533)
    at coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage._invokeUDF(CfJspPage.java:2805)
    at cfrendering2ecfm1331024027$func$INCLUDEFILE.runFunction(Z:\Sites\xamplifier\wheels\controller\rendering.cfm:498)
    at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.invoke(UDFMethod.java:487)
    at coldfusion.filter.SilentFilter.invoke(SilentFilter.java:47)
    at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod$ReturnTypeFilter.invoke(UDFMethod.java:420)
    at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod$ArgumentCollectionFilter.invoke(UDFMethod.java:383)
    at coldfusion.filter.FunctionAccessFilter.invoke(FunctionAccessFilter.java:95)
    at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.runFilterChain(UDFMethod.java:334)
    at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.invoke(UDFMethod.java:533)
    at coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage._invokeUDF(CfJspPage.java:2805)
    at cfrendering2ecfm1331024027$func$RENDERPAGE.runFunction(Z:\Sites\xamplifier\wheels\controller\rendering.cfm:257)
    at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.invoke(UDFMethod.java:487)
    at coldfusion.filter.SilentFilter.invoke(SilentFilter.java:47)
    at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod$ReturnTypeFilter.invoke(UDFMethod.java:420)
    at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod$ArgumentCollectionFilter.invoke(UDFMethod.java:383)
    at coldfusion.filter.FunctionAccessFilter.invoke(FunctionAccessFilter.java:95)
    at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.runFilterChain(UDFMethod.java:334)
    at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.invoke(UDFMethod.java:533)
    at coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage._invokeUDF(CfJspPage.java:2805)
    at cfrendering2ecfm1331024027$funcRENDERPAGE.runFunction(Z:\Sites\xamplifier\wheels\controller\rendering.cfm:68)
    at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.invoke(UDFMethod.java:487)
    at coldfusion.filter.SilentFilter.invoke(SilentFilter.java:47)
    at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod$ReturnTypeFilter.invoke(UDFMethod.java:420)
    at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod$ArgumentCollectionFilter.invoke(UDFMethod.java:383)
    at coldfusion.filter.FunctionAccessFilter.invoke(FunctionAccessFilter.java:95)
    at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.runFilterChain(UDFMethod.java:334)
    at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.invoke(UDFMethod.java:231)
    at coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage._invokeUDF(CfJspPage.java:2840)
    at cfprocessing2ecfm608176556$func$CALLACTION.runFunction(Z:\Sites\xamplifier\wheels\controller\processing.cfm:99)
    at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.invoke(UDFMethod.java:487)
    at coldfusion.filter.SilentFilter.invoke(SilentFilter.java:47)
    at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod$ReturnTypeFilter.invoke(UDFMethod.java:420)
    at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod$ArgumentCollectionFilter.invoke(UDFMethod.java:383)
    at coldfusion.filter.FunctionAccessFilter.invoke(FunctionAccessFilter.java:95)
    at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.runFilterChain(UDFMethod.java:334)
    at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.invoke(UDFMethod.java:533)
    at coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage._invokeUDF(CfJspPage.java:2805)
    at cfprocessing2ecfm608176556$func$PROCESSACTION.runFunction(Z:\Sites\xamplifier\wheels\controller\processing.cfm:60)
    at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.invoke(UDFMethod.java:487)
    at coldfusion.filter.SilentFilter.invoke(SilentFilter.java:47)
    at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod$ReturnTypeFilter.invoke(UDFMethod.java:420)
    at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod$ArgumentCollectionFilter.invoke(UDFMethod.java:383)
    at coldfusion.filter.FunctionAccessFilter.invoke(FunctionAccessFilter.java:95)
    at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.runFilterChain(UDFMethod.java:334)
    at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.invoke(UDFMethod.java:231)
    at coldfusion.runtime.TemplateProxy.invoke(TemplateProxy.java:643)
    at coldfusion.runtime.TemplateProxy.invoke(TemplateProxy.java:432)
    at coldfusion.runtime.TemplateProxy.invoke(TemplateProxy.java:402)
    at coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage._invoke(CfJspPage.java:2483)
    at cfrequest2ecfm2131921479$func$REQUEST.runFunction(Z:\Sites\xamplifier\wheels\dispatch\request.cfm:167)
    at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.invoke(UDFMethod.java:487)
    at coldfusion.filter.SilentFilter.invoke(SilentFilter.java:47)
    at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod$ReturnTypeFilter.invoke(UDFMethod.java:420)
    at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod$ArgumentCollectionFilter.invoke(UDFMethod.java:383)
    at coldfusion.filter.FunctionAccessFilter.invoke(FunctionAccessFilter.java:95)
    at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.runFilterChain(UDFMethod.java:334)
    at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.invoke(UDFMethod.java:231)
    at coldfusion.runtime.TemplateProxy.invoke(TemplateProxy.java:643)
    at coldfusion.runtime.TemplateProxy.invoke(TemplateProxy.java:432)
    at coldfusion.runtime.TemplateProxy.invoke(TemplateProxy.java:402)
    at coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage._invoke(CfJspPage.java:2483)
    at cfindex2ecfm2029461072.runPage(Z:\Sites\xamplifier\wheels\index.cfm:1)
    at coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage.invoke(CfJspPage.java:246)
    at coldfusion.tagext.lang.IncludeTag.handlePageInvoke(IncludeTag.java:736)
    at coldfusion.tagext.lang.IncludeTag.doStartTag(IncludeTag.java:572)
    at coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage._emptyTcfTag(CfJspPage.java:2986)
    at cfindex2ecfm1778521657.runPage(Z:\Sites\xamplifier\index.cfm:1)
    at coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage.invoke(CfJspPage.java:246)
    at coldfusion.tagext.lang.IncludeTag.handlePageInvoke(IncludeTag.java:736)
    at coldfusion.tagext.lang.IncludeTag.doStartTag(IncludeTag.java:572)
    at coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage._emptyTcfTag(CfJspPage.java:2986)
    at cfonrequest2ecfm1108885784$funcONREQUEST.runFunction(Z:\Sites\xamplifier\wheels\events\onrequest.cfm:1)
    at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.invoke(UDFMethod.java:487)
    at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod$ReturnTypeFilter.invoke(UDFMethod.java:420)
    at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod$ArgumentCollectionFilter.invoke(UDFMethod.java:383)
    at coldfusion.filter.FunctionAccessFilter.invoke(FunctionAccessFilter.java:95)
    at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.runFilterChain(UDFMethod.java:334)
    at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.invoke(UDFMethod.java:231)
    at coldfusion.runtime.TemplateProxy.invoke(TemplateProxy.java:643)
    at coldfusion.runtime.TemplateProxy.invoke(TemplateProxy.java:432)
    at coldfusion.runtime.TemplateProxy.invoke(TemplateProxy.java:402)
    at coldfusion.runtime.AppEventInvoker.invoke(AppEventInvoker.java:108)
    at coldfusion.runtime.AppEventInvoker.onRequest(AppEventInvoker.java:301)
    at coldfusion.filter.ApplicationFilter.invoke(ApplicationFilter.java:462)
    at coldfusion.filter.RequestMonitorFilter.invoke(RequestMonitorFilter.java:42)
    at coldfusion.filter.MonitoringFilter.invoke(MonitoringFilter.java:40)
    at coldfusion.filter.PathFilter.invoke(PathFilter.java:142)
    at coldfusion.filter.ExceptionFilter.invoke(ExceptionFilter.java:94)
    at coldfusion.filter.BrowserDebugFilter.invoke(BrowserDebugFilter.java:78)
    at coldfusion.filter.ClientScopePersistenceFilter.invoke(ClientScopePersistenceFilter.java:28)
    at coldfusion.filter.BrowserFilter.invoke(BrowserFilter.java:38)
    at coldfusion.filter.NoCacheFilter.invoke(NoCacheFilter.java:58)
    at coldfusion.filter.GlobalsFilter.invoke(GlobalsFilter.java:38)
    at coldfusion.filter.DatasourceFilter.invoke(DatasourceFilter.java:22)
    at coldfusion.filter.CachingFilter.invoke(CachingFilter.java:62)
    at coldfusion.CfmServlet.service(CfmServlet.java:219)
    at coldfusion.bootstrap.BootstrapServlet.service(BootstrapServlet.java:89)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at coldfusion.monitor.event.MonitoringServletFilter.doFilter(MonitoringServletFilter.java:42)
    at coldfusion.bootstrap.BootstrapFilter.doFilter(BootstrapFilter.java:46)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:422)
    at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProcessor.process(AjpProcessor.java:199)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:314)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: opennlp.tools.util.ObjectStream
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1720)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571)
    ... 145 more
```

Comment: Why are you using `WEB-INF\classes`? That is typically for individual .class files only. For jar files, use `WEB-INF\lib`. Can you post the stack trace message?

Comment: After you move the  OpenNLP jars to `..\lib` and restart, do you still get the error above?  Also, from the piece of the error message we can see, it looks a lot like [the error in your previous thread about CF9](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13479961/using-java-libraries-with-coldfusion-9/14325222#14325222) - any relevance?

Comment: By the way did you already read the article - 'Creating and using a simple Java class' from adobe  
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7880.html
It might be helpful.

Comment: @Leigh my previous thread was when the other developer was working on it and I posted the article for him. That time we got it to work by accident to be honest and it was in a totally different folder. I am only using a single class file that's why I added it under classes. I will need to search more to see if there are any more files associated with this task. Will get back to you soon

Comment: @Geo - If you are using [OpenNLP](https://opennlp.apache.org/), I would be very surprised if only a single class file were involved. So it may well be a missing class. Post the full stack trace so we can figure out the cause. BTW, what you posted above is just the standard error *header*. The header is typically useless (just boilerplate stuff) when working with java objects. The true cause is almost always in the stack trace message.

Comment: I will update my post now. Also I am trying to contact the original developer to enlighten the situation a bit more

Comment: I am trying to recreate it from CF 9 to CF 11. Stack Trace added

Comment: (Edit) It is a missing a class. See `Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: opennlp.tools.util.ObjectStream...` Why do you think only a single class file is involved? Perhaps you are using some custom class built *on top of* the OpenNLP project linked above? If so, it is not just a single class. It is dependent on the OpenNLP jars too. So you need put those jars in the `WEB-INF\lib` folder and restart.

Comment: I am looking into it now. Thanks @Leigh

Comment: @Leigh I found the rest of the jar files and added them in the /lib folder and it works. I have another question though and I don't know if I should start a new thread or not...

Comment: @Geo - Unless it is related to the error above, probably open a new thread.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this is a jar file it needs to go into the /lib directory of the specific ColdFusion instance. The location depends on your type of installation and platform. But it's the same /lib that contains other CF specific jars - look in your CF Admin settings under "system information" or "settings summary" - you will see a long list of jar files that are being loaded upon start. In the one I'm currently looking at (which is a multi-instance cf 9) it is under *instancename*/cfusion.ear/cfusion.war/WEB-INF/cfusion/lib/  but on CF 11 it should be *just* ../WEB-INF/lib.

You can also put it *anywhere* on the server and add th location to the class path file by editing the jvm.config file.

After adding it to /lib or to the classpath you will need to restart ColdFusion. Good luck!

-Mark